# Error in connecting to localhost:9090/v1/health

Tags: docker, docker-compose, whatsapp

While trying Developer setup: Single Instance from WhatsApp Business Api with following documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance#setup

Getting the following error while trying **Initial Setup#Step 7**

```
Their was an error in connecting https://localhost:9090/v1/health
```

Using postman collection as suggested in Step 6. Seems to be docker issue, but not sure.

Any idea?

Comment: did you check whather all the containers are properly running using `docker-compose ps` and checked its logs `docker-compose logs`

Comment: I have the same problem in the navigator is working: {"meta":{"version":"v2.21.6","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1005,"title":"Access denied","details":"Missing or invalid authentication credentials"}]} but in postman i have some problemns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by disabling "SSL Verification" on the postman general settings.

[See this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/postman) on the SSL section for a detailed explanation.